# URL Rewriting in asp.net loses stylesheet mappings

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

i noticed that when using the URL re-writter out of iis 7.0 that the root url character "~" works correctly but when I re-write the url with the global.asax file, the files no longer map correctly.

Why is this and what can I do to have all the files map properly when using global.asax to re-write urls?

```
If URL.Contains("/myurl/") Then
Context.RewritePath("~\myurl.aspx")
end if
```

Comment: Can you plz post ur Style sheet path..

Comment: I agree - can you post the path your page is using to reference your dll?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that the resulting page url no longer refers to a valid location.

If the user is going to `http://www.yoursite.com/myurl/home.aspx` and that page has a reference to a stylesheet at `css/stylesheet.css`, it will be wrong when the path is rewritten.

In this case, the browser will be looking for `http://www.yoursite.com/myurl/css/stylesheet.css`, not `http://www.yoursite.com/css/stylesheet.css`

If your stylesheet reference is relative, you'll need to put a stylesheet reference that refers to the location of the file **from the original URL**.  Otherwise, you could put in a complete path to avoid any problems.